# add cookies using JavaScript when the user click a link

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

my site have two version ( mobile version , pc version )

I want to allow the user which browser the website from mobile to choice the version which he wants.

I added in a footer link when the user click , the browser refresh the page with add cookie browser = pc_version

look at this code but doesn't work with me , I don't know what is the problem

```
<script>
function change_browser(){
   days=30; // number of days to keep the cookie
   myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
   <?php if($_COOKIE['browser'] == 'pc_version'): $browser = 'mobile';else:$browser='pc_version';endif;?>
   document.cookie = 'browser=<?php echo $browser;?>' + ';domain=saudi-hotels.info/;path=/;expires='+ myDate.toGMTString() ;
   window.location = "http://saudi-hotels.info/ar";

}
</script>
<div class="change_mobile">
    <div onclick="change_browser()" style="width:100%;border-radius:none;"  class="go"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you expect and what do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>

function toggleBrowser(){
   var days=30; // number of days to keep the cookie
   var myDate = new Date();
   myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+days);
   var ver = getCookie("browser");
   ver = ver=="mobile"?"pc_version":"mobile";
   setCookie("browser",ver,myDate,"/")
   window.location.reload(1); // assuming same URL
}
/* Cookie functions originally by Bill Dortsch */

function setCookie (name,value,expires,path,theDomain,secure) { 
   var theCookie = name + "=" + escape (value) + 
   ((expires)    ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") + 
   ((path)       ? "; path="    + path   : "") + 
   ((theDomain)  ? "; domain="  + theDomain : "") + 
   ((secure)     ? "; secure"            : ""); 
   document.cookie = theCookie;
} 

function getCookie(Name) { 
   var search = Name + "=" 
   if (document.cookie.length > 0) { // if there are any cookies 
      offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search) 
      if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists 
         offset += search.length 
         // set index of beginning of value 
         end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset) 
         // set index of end of cookie value 
         if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length 
         return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end)) 
      } 
   } 
} 
function delCookie(name,path,domain) {
   if (getCookie(name)) document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path)   ? ";path="   + path   : "") +
      ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "") +
      ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
//   alert(name+' marked for deletion');
}


</script>
<div class="change_mobile">
    <div onclick="toggleBrowser()" style="width:100%;border-radius:none;"  class="go"> </div>
</div>
```